# Can't import pathlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, pathlib

Whenever I write:

```
import pathlib
```

or

```
from pathlib import path
```

I got this:

```
ImportError: No module named pathlib
```

I tried also naming it `os.path`.

I'm on Python 2.7.14

Is pathlib in Python 2 or only in 3?
If it's not available, what else can I use?

Comment: The pathlib module was added sometime in python 3. If you want to use it in python 2 you have to install it: `pip install pathlib`

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
Could you please explain to me how do I do that ?

Comment: ...you paste `pip install pathlib` into a terminal and press Enter. If it doesn't work, you google the error message.

Comment: Sorry if I sound idiot, I'm really just beginning. 
There is no error message per say, but I got a syntax error for "install"... I don't really get it

Comment: @Nonox: Not in a Python interactive session, in a regular `cmd.exe` (Windows) or `bash` (UNIX-like) terminal.

Answer (score 15):

Read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

> ## 11.1. pathlib — Object-oriented filesystem paths
>
> New in version 3.4.

While a very small number of things released after 3.1 made it back to 2.7, the fact that no `pathlib` docs exist in the Python 2 docs should be a giveaway.

[The `os.path` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) does exist in every version, so `import os.path` should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You may install library [pathlib2](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/) by the following command:

`pip install pathlib2`

After that, your import should work:

`import pathlib2 as pathlib`

If you want to use just standard modules, usage of [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) is also possible, but it has another functions and working differently.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

"P" must be capital the code must be

```
from pathlib import Path
```

not

```
from pathlib import path
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34535507)